# Angular NgZorro Datepicker can't use Moment

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm struggling to this problem that I faced.

I have an Angular v9 model with a Moment object and I use NgZorro as UI.
When I bind the Moment object with the DatePicker I have this problem:

> Error: The input date type is not supported ("Date" is now
> recommended)
> at new CandyDate (candy-date.ts:63)

Is there something I'm missing? Or should I use Date to bind that object and, sadly, rewrite a lot of models?

Following, a Stackbliz I created for test:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-rrqepw

Thanks to anyone can (and would) help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading the documentation of [nz-date-picker](https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en#nz-date-picker), the ngModel accept a "Date" object. In your sample, your are using a "moment.Moment" object (created with utc() method). Even the string is partially "wrong" but probably it works due to nzFormat or similar.

Imho the best way is to convert the Moment object to a date:

```
this.editForm.patchValue({ 
  id: 1, 
  desc: 'Awesome description',
  date: now.toDate() // create a Date object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am cannot think of a good way to change the type without physically changing it.  However, you can fairly easily convert it to a date by calling format.

```
 let now = moment.utc().format();
```

or

```
 this.editForm.patchValue({ 
  id: 1,
  desc: 'Awesome description',
  date: now.format(),
});
```